# API call to django server in my React app is returning invalid Json

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I'm trying to connect my frontend react with backend django apps. In django, I defined my model database:

```
from django.db import models

class Departments(models.Model):
    DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    DepartmentName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from EmployeeApp.models import Departments

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = ('DepartmentId', 'DepartmentName')
```

and my views:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from EmployeeApp.models import Departments
from EmployeeApp.serializers import DepartmentSerializer

@csrf_exempt
def departmentApi(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        departments = Departments.objects.all()
        department_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(departments, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(department_serializer.data, safe=False)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        department_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(data=department_data)
        if department_serializer.is_valid():
            department_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add...", safe=False)
    
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)              
        department = Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId = department_data['DepartmentId'])
        department_serializer=DepartmentSerializer(department, data=department_data)              
        if department_serializer.is_valid():
            department_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Sucessfully!",  safe=False) 
        return JsonResponse("Failed to update!", safe=False)
    
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        department = Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=id)
        department.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Succefully!", safe=False)
```

my urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from EmployeeApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('department', views.departmentApi),
    path('department/<int:id>', views.departmentApi)
]
```

my django server runs on http://127.0.0.1:8000/, so I put it in my .env in the react app folder:

```
REACT_APP_API_DEPARTMENT = http://127.0.0.1:8000/department
```

and imported it to use on my Department.jsx component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Department() {
    const [deps, setDeps] = useState([]);

    const refreshList = () => {
        fetch(import.meta.env.REACT_APP_API_DEPARTMENT)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setDeps(data);
          }
          );
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        refreshList();
      }, []);

    return (
        <div className='mt-5 flex justify-start mx-auto'>
            {deps.map((dep) => (
                <div className='border-2 border-black' key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                    <h1>{dep.DepartmentId}</h1>
                    <h1>{dep.DepartmentName}</h1>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
  )
}
```

this, however, returns 4 undefined objects:

[image]

why my react app cant receive nothing from my django url? I tested it on postman and worked just fine

[image]

Comment: Set header `content-type` to `application/json` on your request to the django backend.